# How come the game doesn't end when I lose?

Tags: endless-space

So I just "finished" my first game of Endless Space and was smashed by a ruthless enemy and a failing economy. This was a game vs. only AI players... so I kind of expect some kind of "You lost" screen, instead I still have the "End Turn" button ... I can exit the game and start a new one I suppose...

Is there a way to set it to "auto end turn" so I can see which of the computers wins? Should I just abandon the game and start another? Or maybe this is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

So, in general, 4X Victory conditions can be somewhat arbitrary. There may not be much meaning to winning a massive game by inventing the iPhone or by clobbering the person trying to invent the iPhone. Although the race for "supremacy" is over, there's a lot of maneuvering, expansion, and ship-to-ship action left to squeeze out of this world you've poured hours and hours into.

It's not like you *have* to keep playing. But there's a reason that somebody might, so they let it keep going.

Comment: Because that's what a game *does*.  There are win and lose conditions.  Sorta defeats the whole purpose of a game if you can keep playing after you lose.

Comment: Perhaps you're playing to make a pretty pattern in your star systems, or develop the very first species to invent underarm deodorant before the wheel - and then you forgot to disable the victory conditions. There are plenty of reasons to play a complex 4X game that aren't specifically about winning.